# PHP - simple POST not working but GET does

Tags: php, forms, post

I have two forms on a page - one POSTs to the same file, the other POSTs to another file. The first form when submitted successfully POSTs to the page and an associated VarDump gives expected values however, the second script fails to POST successfully to the next page.

The forms are identical: 
 
**Form 1**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" value="stuff" name="test" />
    <input type="submit" value="see test" name="testsubmit" />
</form>
```

**Form 2**

```
<form name="stuff" action="../artwork" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="stuff" name="test" />
    <input type="submit" value="next"  name="submit" />
</form>
```

Data is received at the other end when using GET; only POST doesn't work.
Before I'm asked - other POST forms are working on the server in almost identical conditions, it is just this form that isn't working.

Comment: Is your page really `../artwork` or does irt have a file extension? Look in the error logs.

Comment: Put here your code on backend-php server.

Comment: It is really `.../artwork`, another script processes the page and removes .php extensions.

Comment: What do you see in your error logs?

Comment: Nothing - no errors, just a null POST value.

Comment: What is the full path to access the page with the second form on your website? Can you load the `../artwork` URL from there? In other words, if the form is at `http://example.com/pages/my_form`, is the URL `http://example.com/artwork` a valid page?

Comment: The full url is `http://example.com/dir/my_form` and it is posting to `http://example.com/dir/artwork` hence either going down one directory `../artwork` or going to root and up two `/dir/artwork` will work. The address is not the issue - the expected page is loading; just minus POST data.

Comment: @Unk doing `../` is actually going _up_ and going into a child directory is going _down_

Comment: We need to see your backend

Comment: @developius As previously established, the other code is not the issue - other POST variables are going through

Comment: @Unk "Interesting note - data is received at the other end when using GET; only POST doesn't work...!", are you _sure_ you have the `$_POST` setup in your PHP?

Comment: @developius Please read the question - if POST wasn't set up then it wouldn't be POSTing full stop!

Comment: @Unk it would, the client doesn't care about the server

Comment: @unk from what you've said, the form in `http://example.com/pages/my_form` is posting to `http://example.com/artwork` (`action="../artwork"`), which is what `http://example.com/pages/my_form/../artwork` resolves to. If you're looking at the `$_POST` contents in `/dir/artwork`, it should be empty, because nothing is posting to it. Do you have a redirect set up for `/artwork` going to `/dir/artwork`? I don't think the `POST` data would traverse that redirect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This actually turned out to be a very strange server issue where POST was "blocked" somehow. We don't know how as it is allowed in Apache and enabled in PHP, we think it is to do with the way pages are loaded (as POST to certain pages which are in a totally different directory work).

Solution: use sessions and GET.

Answer (score -1):

`action="../artwork"`
you are missing file extension. It should be artwork.php and also check whether there is a artwork.php file in upper folder.

Comment: A file extension is not strictly required, and is not necessarily the problem.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is not required. but do you think that a RewriteCond  is written in his case if you consider the nature of question?

Comment: OP said "It is really .../artwork, another script processes the page and removes .php extensions" ~40 minutes before your answer.

Comment: Yeah, the script that 'removes' the extension is working and other pages with POST data are running fine through it - just not this one!

Answer (score -1):

Try having an uppercase `method` value.

`<form name="stuff" action="../artwork" method="POST">`